# How do you change author for an existing git commit without using the terminal?

Tags: git, github, terminal, command-line-interface

So I have 2 GitHub accounts (1 work and 1 personal) and I have set up SSH keys to be used on 2 laptops (1 work and 1 personal). I created a repo on my personal acc, and cloned it to my work laptop (making sure I had the correct SSH link). However I forgot to set author to be my personal acc so it was set to my work acc name which is globally configured. Now I can't seem to clone the repo to my personal laptop and I think it's due to it having the commits from my work acc. This is the error I get when I try to clone it:

```
Cloning into 'notes'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I know I can change the author using `git commit --amend --author="John Doe <john@doe.org>"` but how can I without having the cloned repo? Is there a way to do it without using the terminal?

Comment: You can have different keys for different emails on GitHub. I don't think you can change the author without a terminal.

Comment: Yeah I do have different keys for both of my emails on GitHub. Now I have to wait until tomorrow when I have access to my work laptop and then change the author there T_T

Comment: This seems to be an [X-Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/232644) problem to me. Access via ssh keys is a github feature which ties into your github account, and not the email information associated with a commit. As the error reads, this is a permission issue with the ssh key for the account. As workaround, you can add the https url for the repo as a remote in your local copy and use this to fetch changes.

Comment: @mu無 thanks! I solved it using the https link like you said

Comment: @pinglinh Happy to help. It would be better if you edited the post with a suitable title, and added more information in your answer so that it helps others in future.

Comment: I think it's perfectly valid. It's also pretty detailed :)

Answer (score 2):

This was solved by cloning with https url instead of SSH.